# jQuery custom namespaced event being triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, namespaces

I have run into a problem with custom events with namespaces.

If I bind an event callback, specifying my custom event namespace, the callback will be made twice. Once when I trigger it using the namespace as expected, but also when the event is trigged with no namespace.

It appears to me that when binding to an event with a specified namespace, the callback should not be trigged for the non-namespaced event.

**Question:** Am I experiencing a bug with jQuery event binding, or should I be handling my events using the stated workaround?  I am looking for best practice in this instance.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
$(document).on('myevent.mynamespace', function (e) {console.log(e);});
$(document).trigger('myevent.mynamespace');
$(document).trigger('myevent');
```

**Output: (console)**

```
_.Event {type: "myevent", timeStamp: 1432746225028, jQuery21109806629773229361: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: "mynamespace"…}
_.Event {type: "myevent", timeStamp: 1432746225033, jQuery21109806629773229361: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: ""…}
```

**Expected:**

```
_.Event {type: "myevent", timeStamp: 1432746225028, jQuery21109806629773229361: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: "mynamespace"…}
```

**Work Around:**

```
$(document).on('myevent.mynamespace', function (e) {
  // break out if the namespace does not match as expected
  if (e.namespace !== 'mynamespace') return;
  console.log(e);
});
$(document).trigger('myevent.mynamespace');
$(document).trigger('myevent');
```

Comment: Cannot you instead use a custom event?

Comment: I was thinking it should essentially treat this as a custom event, due to the namespace.  `ready` for my plugin, using the plugins namespace. I could rename it to something different and be done with the problem, but I'm unsure if that should be necessary. I feel like the second event (doc ready) should never have been fired for my namespaced bind.

Comment: Issue is that internally, jQuery use `jQuery( document ).triggerHandler( "ready" );` once DOM is ready without taking into account any namespace. So that's why it is fired twice. Now why do you trigger it manually?

Comment: And if you for some reason you still want to trigger it, this could be a workaround too: `$(document).trigger('ready.namespacetest').off('ready.namespacetest');`

Comment: `It appears to me that when binding to an event with a specified namespace, it should not trigger the callback for the non-namespaced event.` But the ready event is fired once the DOM is ready (calling your ready namespaced too which you have already called manually), so in fact, i don't see any issue here

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time! I trigger the namespaced event manually to provide a way to hook in after a specific process has been completed.  I could just rename it as you suggest, that would be a reasonable solution.  However, could the current implementation for finding which callbacks to fire be broken based on the fact I have requested my callback to only fire with a specific namespace. `$(document).on('ready.namespacetest', ...`

Comment: Hi @A.Wolff I have updated my question to remove ambiguity with the 'ready' event. This pattern occurs with any event name, when triggering without a namespace, bindings with namespace are run.

Comment: But that's expected behaviour. If you want to trigger specific type of event excluding the ones namespaced of same type, you can use `$elem.trigger("click.$");` but this is actually the opposite of what you seem to want.

Comment: It would be expected behaviour if i were binding with no namespace `$(document).on('myevent', ...)`, this way i would expect my callback to be fired regardless of namespace.  But as I _am_ specifying a namespace in my bind i would not expect my callback to be fired unless that namespace was in the event.

Comment: But it would be really really hard to manage if it was the case. Because for each event bind using namespace, you would have to call it explicitely.